# Smartform crashes when I try to create text saying macro not found

Tags: abap, sap-smart-forms

Hello I'm using ECC6 EHP7 server, When I try to create 'text' in Smartform, it is crashing saying no macros found.

I have taken the screen shots of the error and attached below, so someone please help me what configurations I need to do get rid of my error.

This is what I get when I try to create text

[image]

If I click on Show Help I this is what, it is showing

[image]

These are the steps it is showing

[image]

[image]

I have tried all steps but still my smartform transaction is crashing during text creation.

Comment: It is crashing after you press "OK"? Transaction crashes or the whole SAPgui?

Comment: Check the SAP notes relevant to your SAP GUI and Microsoft Word versions. If you search "The macro cannot be found or has been disabled because of your Macro security settings", you'll get there: [SAP support note 2512311](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/2512311)

Comment: Thank you Sandra Rossi, you made my day easy, actually it was a version problem with my MS office, EHP7.40 release is not compatible with MS office x64 bit, but after your suggestion I have tried to uninstall, my current MS office and installed x32 bit MS Office, this is compatible with EHP7.40 and this is working fine.